# how to append url with component's name in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I want to add the component's name to the URL in Ember js.

Example:

If the main URL is : localhost:4200/home ,
then in home,if I call/redirect to a component(say - abc), the URL should get appended:

localhost:4200/abc
or 
localhost:4200/home/abc

Comment: I have recently started learning and working on ember js.

Comment: It seems - for pages which are created as route will be shown on URL - if we redirect to them .

Example: if there are route for login, home , forgot password. and home contains all the components of web application. Then url can have /login, /home, or /forgot-password. 

any component(say abc) inside home can't be shown on url  , like /abc or /home/abc

please let me know, if my understanding is correct

Comment: You've said that you are new to Ember, so I'm betting that this is not a special edge case. I believe the answer is to change the way you are thinking about this. Instead of trying to make a component act like a route, just use a route - and put the component in that route's template.

Answer (score 1):

> If the main URL is : localhost:4200/home , then in home,if I
>   call/redirect to a component(say - abc), the URL should get appended:

How do you call/redirect to a component in ember?. If you got some hacky way to do that, then I will encourage you not to do this.
In Ember, the router matches the current URL to the routes that you've defined.

If you got `/home/abc` URL path, it means you have `abc` route nested inside `home` route.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', function() {
    this.route('abc');
  });
});
```

If you know all routes will come under home route, then you can define it manually. Suppose if you don't know or what will come , then go for [defining the dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) in URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `{{component}}` helper.

You need to define dynamic path for home and send the component name from url to home controller by `model` hook.

Below are essential parts of the solution.

```
//router.js
this.route('home', {path: 'home/:cmp'});

//routes/home.js
model(params){
  return params.cmp;
}

//templates/home.hbs
{{component model}}
```

Please take a look at [this tiwddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/cc0219e791ab1c828db8e3cf5d201cc5)